# Big List of Fun Math Books

Tags: big-list, recreational-mathematics

To be on this list the book must satisfy the following conditions:

1. It doesn't require an enormous amount of background material to understand.
2. It must be a fun book, either in recreational math (or something close to) or in philosophy of math.

Here are my two contributions to the list:

1. What is Mathematics? Courant and Robbins.
2. Proofs that Really Count. Benjamin and Quinn.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of big lists. Not that it matters.

Comment: I find well-written textbooks more fun than "recreational math" books.

Comment: Yeah, you're probally right. However, many textbooks require a lot of background material, which is why I decided to restrict the books to the above categories.

Comment: I wonder if Gardner's books count...

Comment: @lhf You're also not a small fan of small lists, small lists are ok.

Comment: [Real questions have answers, not items.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) [Avoid asking subjective questions where… every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”; your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: I'm curious how you missed du Sautoy: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Marcus-Du-Sautoy/e/B001JOS6XY

Comment: This answer should be closed as off-topic.  Besides, it's a dup of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275/best-maths-books-for-non-mathematicians/364#364) anyways.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Math.SE has accepted big-lists, especially as comm-wiki, and this is a different question to the one you suggested: I wouldn't have even thought of my answer for that question.

Comment: I think answers are much better if they say something about why the books are suited for the list.  Chris Dugale: Could you please add why your two contributions are answers?

Answer (score 29):

*Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid*, by Douglas Hofstadter. *Very* interesting read - details Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem, and manages to touch on a wide variety of topics, including genetics, reductionism/holism, programming, art, music, brains, zen, language, etc. The central idea is that a special kind of self-reference (which Hofstadter calls *a strange loop*) seems to pop up everywhere, and is perhaps at the heart of intelligence and the appearance of meaning in a structure made up of meaningless parts.

Comment: +1 I love this book very much~~~ For the amazing coincidence among the three masters~~ And the unify of math, logic, art and music!

Answer (score 19):

A whole lot of books by Raymond Smullyan, but *To Mock a Mockingbird*, which presents combinatory logic is definitely on the list, as is one of the several books in which he presents Gödel's  first incompleteness theorem as a knights-and-knaves puzzle.

Comment: To Mock A Mockingbird is my favorite of Smullyan's books by far (which is saying a lot), probably because it takes a different angle towards his usual topics.

Answer (score 18):

- *Flatland*, by E. A. Abbott, and its sequel *Sphereland* by Dionys Burger.

Answer (score 13):

So, my favorite recreational math book growing up was *Mathematical Mysteries*, by Calvin Clawson.  It's light on rigor, but it contains a lot of interesting mathematical concepts.

Also, I think it's important to list Herbert Robbins as an author when talking about *What is Mathematics?*, seeing how he was the one doing the actual writing.

Comment: +1 for giving credit to Robbins - he is too often missed out.

Answer (score 12):

I am quite prepared to be down-voted on this one, but here goes ...

I would have to include Andre Weil's book "Basic Number Theory", since:

1. All the mathematicians I know regard basic number theory as fun and recreational.
2. The author states in the preface: "No knowledge of number theory is pre-supposed in this book, except for the most elementary facts about rational integers".

Comment: the end of the sentence should be added "; it is useful but not necessary to have some superficial acquaintance with the p-adic valuation of the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers and with the completion $\mathbb{Q}_p$  of $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by these valuations." and the four pages of prerequisites following... :-)

Comment: Ah yes!! - I wish I had know about those sentences before I actually parted with my money and bought this book :-)

Comment: Very funny answer! +1

Answer (score 12):

I recommend [Proofs from THE BOOK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK) by Aigner and Ziegler. [Here](http://www.ams.org/notices/199907/rev-ullman.pdf) you can find a review.

Answer (score 10):

This is a topic that has been hit pretty well at MO in a few ways.

The most related question would be [favorite popular math book](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8609/favorite-popular-math-book), which has 60 answers and many (more than 60) books mentioned, along with their author(s) and a short description.

The question [how to write popular mathematics well](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84025/how-to-write-popular-mathematics-well) has some related bits, too. And on a not-so-recreational-level, there is the question [Examples of great mathematical writing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358/examples-of-great-mathematical-writing), which includes everything by Serre and the analysis series by Stein and Shakarchi.

Answer (score 10):

It is interesting that no one has mentioned these two so far.

[Journey through Genius: The Great Theorems of Mathematics by William Dunham](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014014739X)

[The Music of the Primes: Searching to Solve the Greatest Mystery in Mathematics by Marcus du Sautoy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060935588)

Answer (score 9):

- *One, Two, Three… Infinity* by George Gamow

Answer (score 8):

To my opinion Polya, G. "Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning" would go here as philosophy of math and a recreational book as well with many problems and examples, illustrating some well-known mathematical discoveries of past.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add "A Budget of Trisectors" by Underwood Dudley.  It's the author's experiences with false constructions of an angle trisection with compass and straightedge, and has some very interesting debates about what proofs are and how to explain them to the layperson.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, they are priced quite expensively, but the four volumes of [Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811306) are simply wonderful.  It can be fairly heavy reading (I've only skimmed parts of the various volumes), but it provides directly accessible mathematics without any prerequisite requirements.

Comment: +1 : this is the book I was going to mention when I had a few minutes to answer.  A delight from start to finish.

Answer (score 6):

Most introductory Dover books are pretty cheap and don't require too much background.

For example, Pinter's `A Book of Modern Algebra` is, in my opinion, quite well written and rich with exercises. (it lacks answers to all but a few questions, though).

`The Number Devil: A Mathematical Adventure` by Hans Enzensberger is a fun survey of elementary number theory. It's structured similarly to the series of children's books 'Diary of a Wimpy Kid.'

Answer (score 5):

Some freshly bought ones:

- [The Universe in Zero Words: The Story of Mathematics as Told through Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691152829)
- [Elliptic Tales: Curves, Counting, and Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691151199)
- [Mathletics: A Scientist Explains 100 Amazing Things About the World of Sports](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393063410)
- [The Unfinished Game: Pascal, Fermat, and the Seventeenth-Century Letter that Made the World Modern (Basic Ideas)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023RT090)

Answer (score 5):

*The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers* by David Wells is a good read.

Comment: I was going to mention that one, but you beat me to it, by 5 years. Well, anyway, I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

- [Where Mathematics Comes From: How the Embodied Mind Brings

  Mathematics into Being](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465037712)
- [The manga Guide to Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593274130)
- [The Manga Guide to Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271948)
- [Logicomix: An Epic Search for Truth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1596914521)
- [Head First Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596514867)

Answer (score 4):

The book that inspired me to change majors from chemistry to mathematics and kept me going through the dark times during my father's cancer: *I Want To Be A Mathematician*  by Paul Halmos. It is an addicting read with so much that is wise about mathematics, mathematicians and the entire culture surrounding them.It should be required reading for any new mathematics student.

Answer (score 4):

I really enjoyed [Fermat's Enigma](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385493622) by Simon Singh. This definitely falls more under the heading "philosophy of math", but it's great in conveying to laypersons (like me) what an interesting and thrilling field mathematics is.

Answer (score 4):

[*The Shape of Space*](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Shape_of_Space.html?id=Lurp6nB4LtQC) by Jeffrey Weeks

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Ferguson's *Game Theory* is a really fun read (and it's available for free [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/Contents.html))

Answer (score 3):

One Minute Mysteries: 65 Short Mysteries You Solve With Math!

simply for the sheer whimsy of reading a book written by a 9-year-old.

Also because you can e-borrow it for free:

http://cabq.lib.overdrive.com/60B9DEC2-1F68-4176-9A45-E3063BE05F2F/10/412/en/ContentDetails.htm?ID=8F3444CD-925D-4C7E-B178-CAB18505435A

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematics and the Imagination*, by Edward Kasner and James R. Newman.

Answer (score 2):

*The Man Who Counted*, Malba Tahan

Answer (score 2):

Both of the following books are really interesting and very accessible.

[Stewart, Ian - Math Hysteria](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198613369)
This book covers the math behind many famous games and puzzles and requires very little math to be able to grasp. Very light hearted and fun.

[Bellos, Ales - Alex's Adventures in Numberland](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Alexs-Adventures-Numberland-Dispatches-Mathematics/dp/0747597162)
This book is about maths in society and everyday life, from monkeys doing arithmetics to odds in Las Vegas.

Comment: G.E.B. would also have been a nice choice but it's already listed and to be fair, while it doesn't require specific math knowledge per se, I think it does require a certain knowledge of mathematical thinking.

Answer (score 2):

**Does God Play Dice?** The New Mathematics of Chaos by **Ian Stewart**

This book explains very nicely about a very complicated topic. I liked simple calculator example which shows chaos with a basic equation like $x^2$

[http://www.amazon.com/Does-Play-Dice-Mathematics-Chaos/dp/0631232516](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631232516)

**How to Cut a Cake**: And Other Mathematical Conundrums by **Ian Stewart**

This one is pure fun.

[http://www.amazon.com/How-Cut-Cake-Mathematical-Conundrums/dp/0199205906/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1342164338&sr=1-1&keywords=how+to+cut+a+cake](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199205906)

Answer (score 2):

**The Prime Number Theorem** by G. J. O. Jameson is a delightful read.

Answer (score 0):

The book

Which Way Did the Bicycle Go?: And Other Intriguing Mathematical Mysteries (Dolciani Mathematical Expositions)

by Joseph D. E. Konhauser