# Big list of serious but fun "unusual" books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, big-list, book-recommendation

I would like to have some suggestions about serious (that is, with good mathematical content) but fun books that cover topics (or propose problems)

- in "recreational mathematics";
- in any other field (but from a perspective that is not presented in standard university courses).

For example, I would appreciate some references to books by **Martin Gardner** and **John Conway**.

---

I really liked the answers given to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264371/fun-but-serious-mathematics-books-to-gift-advanced-undergraduates?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) and to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168019/big-list-of-fun-math-books), in particular:

- *On Numbers and Games*, by John Conway (which was not an answer actually);
- *Generatingfunctionology*, by Herbert Wilf;
- *The Symmetries of Things*, by John Conway;
- *The Sensual (Quadratic) Form*, by John Conway.

But I would like to know other opinions on the books proposed in **these  threads** and on **other** books (also **newly published** ones).

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since it's [already in one of the threads](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/168070/24875) you linked, but *To Mock a Mockingbird* by Raymond Smullyan deserves mention.

Comment: Irresistible integrals maybe

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do those threads not satisfy your question?  Math.SE isn't really a discussion site, so 'opinions about the books people have listed elsewhere' IMHO isn't a great topic for a question in and of itself.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This is a good point, but -- as I said -- I would like to know if there are *other* worthwhile books that were not mentioned in these threads (and newly published ones). And, for example, Pedro Tamaroff's answer is surely a great addition in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some more books which are informative *and also provide fun*!

> **Combinatorics**
>
> If you like *Generatingfunctionology* by Herbert Wilf then *of course* you will also like
>
> - [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) by *Graham*, *Knuth* & *Patashnik*.
>
> With respect to the authors, especially Donald E. Knuth no comments are necessary to this book from my side besides, this is a *wonderful book* - this is an *informative book* - this book is **pure reading fun**. It's extremely valuable if you're interested in combinatorics and as *Wilf's GF* is a perfect starter this book is a great follow-up to deepen the knowledge. One of many amusing ideas was to dedicate the margin to comments of some of his student's:
>
> *From the Preface*: Students always know better than their teachers, so we have asked the first students of this material to contribute their frank opinions, as *graffiti* in the margins. Some of these marginal markings are merely corny, some are profound; some of them warn about ambiguities or obscurities, others are ...
>
> *Note:* I've answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742083) about specific books in combinatorics and it was (and is) a problem for me to restrict myself to the most concise information and therefore decided not to mention this brilliant book.
>
> **Experimental Mathematics**
>
> This relatively new, exciting and challenging discipline provides us with fascinating mathematics.  Leading experts in this discipline are the *Borwein Brothers* [Jonathan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Borwein) and [Peter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Borwein). I strongly recommend all of their books, especially:
>
> - [Mathematics by Experiment - Plausible Reasoning in the $21^{\text{st}}$ Century](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814429) by Jonathan Borwein and David Bailey.
>
> If you take a look at the *table of contents* of the referenced link, maybe you will also  find it funny, exciting and informative. It's interesting, since they often share with us the *way how they found deep and interesting results* and this is pure fun for me! In the same spirit are their follow-ups:
>
> - [The Computer as Crucible: An Introduction to Experimental Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568813430) and some more.
>
> The material in these books is most of the time accessible and not too hard, but to get an impression of the art of these guys and their beautiful math you may have a look at this article: [Ramanujan, Modular Equations and Approximations to Pi or How to Compute  One Billion Digits of Pi](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/%7Epborwein/PAPERS/P40.pdf) by the *Borwein Brothers* and *D.H. Bailey*.
>
> Of course, *Ramanujan* and *beautiful math* is often strongly connected :-)

Comment: @Dal: Thanks again for the bounty! I didn't expect to receive three bounties from you in a row! :-)

Comment: The link "this question" should probably point to question 742083, not 74208.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thank's! I've updated the link accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a few off the top of my head.

- *Experiments in Topology*, Stephen Barr
- *On Knots*, Louis Kauffman
- *Gödel, Escher, Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid*, Douglas Hofstadter
- *1,2,3, infinity*, George Gamow

I've made this community wiki, so other people can feel free to edit this post and add to the list.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Good examples are:

- Havil: *Gamma*
- Aigner, Ziegler: *Proofs from THE BOOK*
- Schroeder:    *Number Theory in Science and Communication*
- Arnold: *Catastrophe Theory*
- Tabachnikov: *Geometry and Billiards*
- Markowich: *Applied    Partial Differential Equations*
- Pesic: *Abel's Proof*
- Harel:    *Computers Ltd.*

Comment: These seem all very good. Thank you so much. Any other input from you is highly appreciated :)

Comment: @Dal: That is fine! Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

*Every* book by Edmund Landau is certainly interesting to look at. Wiener used to say about his style that "His books read like a Sears-Roebuck catalogue." Personally, I've read his Zahlentheorie and his two books on introductory calculus and foundations of analysis. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Landau) has a small list (the three books I mentioned and their corresponding ISBNs). There are further publications, but not in english. His Lectures on Number Theory continue for 3 or 4 more volumes, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. But would you mind adding to your answer a bibliography?

Comment: not in English? If it were in Esperanto, that would be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three popular books I read a little over a year ago.  I enjoyed each one enormously, and I even managed to learn a thing or two - mind you, I was starting from a pretty narrow perspective.

- *The Music of the Primes*; Marcus du Sautoy
- *Infinity and the Mind*; Rudolph Rucker
- *Beyond the Limits of Thought*; Graham Priest

The first looks at the Riemann hypothesis, the second looks at set theory.  These are popular (non-technical) books, but they both do a very good job with their subjects.  The third book looks at how concepts often break-down into paradox when pushed to the limit. An obvious example being unrestricted set formation giving rise to, for example, Russell's paradox.  It is more philosophical in tone than mathematical, but the subject matter is logic and mathematics. I've read a few other popular books, but have not found them worth mentioning.

(I am tempted to mention Russell and Whitehead's Principia Mathematica, but it is not to all tastes and I am particularly dull.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions:

1. Linderholm's *Mathematics Made Difficult*
2. Manin's *Mathematics as Metaphor*.

Answer (score 0):

There are [three](https://press.princeton.edu/our-authors/rosenhouse-jason) books so far in the series, The Mathematics of Various Entertaining Subjects. They are all, indeed, entertaining, with serious mathematical content.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the book *Magical maze* by Ian Stuart.

It is a narration involving two guys and a maze where concepts are introduced one by one. It gave me a new way of thinking about graphs and where it may be useful.