# Mathematics Article Collection Books for Talented High School Students

Tags: reference-request, education

I'm looking for some good books including mathematics articles which are appropriate for talented high school students. I'm **NOT** looking for puzzle or Olympiad problem books. Here are some of my findings, which may serve as examples:

- [Strange Curves, Counting Rabbits, & Other Mathematical Explorations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691127972).
- [How to Guard an Art Gallery and Other Discrete Mathematical
  Adventures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801892996).
- [Kvant Selecta: Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821717).
- [Kvant Selecta: Algebra and Analysis, 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821810022).
- [Kvant Selecta: Algebra and Analysis, 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821819151).

Do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Prasolov's 'Essays on Numbers and Figures' and Rademacher & Toeplitz's 'The Enjoyment of Mathematics' (which is better I think).

Comment: @MariusKempe Are these recommended by V. I. Arnold?

Comment: @Anuar: Well, 'The Enjoyment of Mathematics' was one of the first math books Arnold read, and it made a great and lasting impression on him...

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather large list available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275/73025).

I would add to it (for really strong students)

- V. Prasolov, Y. Solovyev [Elliptic Functions and Elliptic Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821805878).

*This book is devoted to the geometry and arithmetic of elliptic curves and to elliptic functions with applications to algebra and number theory. It includes modern interpretations of some famous classical algebraic theorems such as Abel's theorem on the lemniscate and Hermite's solution of the fifth degree equation by means of theta functions. Suitable as a text, the book is self-contained and assumes as prerequisites only the standard one-year courses of algebra and analysis.*

Comment: There is another book by Prasolov, a collection 12 essays which are actually talks given to highschool students. But I do not remember the title.

Answer (score 1):

I read Holme's *A Royal Road to Algebraic Geometry* in my sophomore year of high school. It's relatively tough to get through, but definitely doable and worth the effort.